# Convergence with p integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am unsure if this integral is convergent or not based on the $p$ rule that if $P$ is greater than one, it is convergent?
$$\int_\pi^\infty\frac{1+\sin(x)}{x^2} \; dx$$
and since $1+\sin(x)$ is always positive, it can be replaced with any integer greater or equal to one?

Answer (score 4):

One may observe that
$$0\leq\int_\pi^\infty\frac{1+\sin(x)}{x^2} \; dx\leq\int_\pi^\infty\frac{2}{x^2} \; dx=\frac{2}{\pi }$$

Comment: as fast as possible +1

Comment: Okay, so since 2 over infinity can be approximated as 0, then it converges on 2 over pi?

Comment: @MarcD. Yes, thanks.